# What tool do I need for measuring DC power consumption of device over a period of time?

Tags: power, dc

I have a device that's being battery powered and I would like to measure the power consumption over a longer period of time (~24Hours). I want to read both the voltage of my battery and the current being drawn by my device. I would need something battery powered that could log the data into a raw .csv like format so I can later run analytics on it.

I know this should be really simple but I'm not exactly sure what to Google to find what I need for this application.

Edit: Hoping not more than ~$500. Looking at 12V-48VDC and current <10A. However I would like fairly high accuracy because my application is very sensitive to power consumption. Rate could be on the order of seconds...maybe even minutes but doesn't need to be miliseconds.

Comment: Welcome fullyjosh. What is your budget? You could either buy a current logger with this functionality but could cost 50 - 150 dollars. You could also built something yourself fairly easily (and cheap) with for example an Arduino or Raspberry Pi.

Comment: A lot depends on what voltage and current you want to log, and at what rate. If your device is particularly low power (or spends a lot of time asleep) then measurement is more of a challenge. Try to define your requirements: 1. number of log entries   2. Voltage range.   3. Current range.

Comment: It's going to be hard to make the meter itself battery powered.  Consider something like an INA219 on an Arduino or similar to rapidly take and totalize readings giving periodic summary output to a PC or raspberry pi which saves them.

Comment: @ChrisStratton good idea although IMA219 won't allow for the specced 48 VDC unfortunately.

Comment: @JanDorniak indeed, but that requirement was only added in an edit long after the comment.  Hall sensors might, though the scope of the power requirement in combination with the very low sampling rate requirement raises the question if the installed battery capacity is actually up to the task.

Comment: @ChrisStratton do you maybe know of an equivalent (even with just analog voltage output, without I2C) which goes up to 50V? As far as I know TI's INA series only goes up to 36 unfortunately. Or should this just be built using a regular opamp circuit?

Answer (score 1):

There are few options for such a task:

1. A DMM with data logging capability. You need two of them, one for current and one for voltage.
2. A DAQ board, an analog front end to convert the current into voltage and a PC. You will need one with 2 channels and sufficient resolution and for your requirements.
3. A purpose build device for such task - usually they are called IoT power monitors or something similar. Such a device implements the ADC and analog circuitry, you will need a PC to complete the system.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Arduino and can tinker it you can try the building [ACS712 Current Sensor And Arduino](https://www.makerguides.com/acs712-current-sensor-and-arduino-a-complete-guide/).

1. For the Arduino you can set-up two channels to measure a) Voltage and b) Current through the ACS712 sensor.
2. Another way is to just measure current by measuring the voltage through a "sense" resistor but this extra resistance affects the load current by a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It should be pointed out that this is actually quite difficult to do accurately, even for professionals. Modern devices often draw huge bursts of current, followed by long periods of almost nothing. Either of these states is easy to measure, but not both at the same time.

A common work around is to measure these states separately (force sleep state,  then force active state). And simply sum up the time the device spends in each of these states.

Measuring the voltage drop in a battery might also work well. If you profile the battery before, and after that should be pretty accurate. It also *the most* similar to real world conditions you can get.

Comment: Why would measuring bursty current over a long time be harder than less bursty current?  You can always turn a bursty current into a slowly varying current with a filter.

Comment: Give it some numbers and you'll see. Device draws 200mA for 1 second. Then 2uA for 10 minutes. Make a circuit to measure that. The capacitor to average 200mA down to say ..10uA would be huge, and then you've got leakage to compensate for.

Comment: You can use a huge turn down ratio, but then your accuracy will suffer.

Comment: I thought you meant bursty at nanosecond time scales (e.g. transients), in which case you just filter.  If you mean measuring average currents over a large dynamic range, you need a 16 bit ADC.  I guess that might be more expensive but it isn't really difficult per se.  For what it is worth, when I had to characterize a microcontroller's battery usage, I spent a couple hundred dollars on a NI USB DAQ board, which worked great for the application.